# Can the package "org.opencv.core.Mat" be used for a simple Java program?

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv

I'm trying to do some operations with a Matrix in Java using opencv.  I'm using Eclipse Kepler IDE.

The problem happens when I try to declare a new matrix with the constructor, then I get the following error in the console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
    org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(III)J
at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(Native Method)
at org.opencv.core.Mat.<init>(Mat.java:477)
```

I'm using OpenCV 2.4.8 for OSX, OSX 10.9.1 and Eclipse Kepler.

Here is my Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Size;

public class FisherFaces {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Size s = new Size(new double[] {3,3});
    Mat g= new Mat(3,3,CvType.CV_8UC1);

}
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong to cause this error?

Comment: I found the problems, I wasn't loading the native libraries,adding the line    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); fixes it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the problem, I wasn't loading the native libraries, adding the line below fixes it.

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
```

Comment: Where to add this line??

Comment: From http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html: Note the call to System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME). This command must be executed exactly once per Java process prior to using any native OpenCV methods. If you don’t call it, you will get UnsatisfiedLink errors. You will also get errors if you try to load OpenCV when it has already been loaded.

Comment: @Pranita I added this command as the first line in the main() method. But this line was not completely running and I had to edit it to locate the DLL file correctly. I used load() rather than loadLibrary() and prepended the Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME by the path of the DLL file. Finally, the .dll extension is added at the end to form the absolute path of the DLL file. The line I used is "System.load("D:\\OpenCV\\opencv-3.0.0\\opencv\\build\\java\\x64\\"+Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME+".dll");" Remember to use x64 or x86 depending on your system.